# Cookie PHP not set

Tags: php, cookies

I'am trying to set a cookie in a php file (yesterday it worked, today it does not)

I made the cookie and now i'm trying to delete is by setting it to a null-value. Still the cookie is not being made.

I already deleted the cookies in my browser aswell.

Can someone help me?

```
    setcookie("winkelwagen", "", '/');

    if(!isset($_COOKIE["winkelwagen"])) {
        echo "<br>Cookie is not set!";
    } else {
        echo "<br>Cookie '" . $_COOKIE["winkelwagen"] . "' is set!";
        echo "<br>Value is: " . $_COOKIE["winkelwagen"];

    }
```

I'm getting "Cookie is not set" as output

Comment: FYI: You cannot access cookie on the same request after setting it. Cookies are sent by browser as a part of HTTP Request Headers. And Cookies are sent by server as a part of HTTP Response Headers. So your HTTP request will not have the cookie which you are just setting in the response.

Comment: After a page reload it also says 'cookie not set'

Answer (score 2):

This is supposed to fail / the expected behaviour:

```
setcookie("winkelwagen", "", '/');

if(!isset($_COOKIE["winkelwagen"])) {
    echo "<br>Cookie is not set!";
}
```

According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) (emphasis added by me):

> Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the **next page
>   load** with the $_COOKIE or $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS arrays.

So your cookie will never be available when you set it, it will be available on the next page you load.

Comment: Yesterday I did try this: setcookie("winkelwagen", ""); and the output (echo's) were fine. it said cookie ... is set.

Comment: @user3475797 It will be if you have loaded the page before. Probably a previous cookie expired somewhere today / yesterday.

Comment: The thing is, even if i make a cookie with another name, that cookie is also not being created

Comment: @user3475797 Also check the manual for the exact order / meaning of the parameters.

Comment: I am only using the name and value parameters

Comment: The parameters are incorrect in his example, also with the empty value

Comment: @sergio Yep, it's a combination of both our answers :-)

Comment: Is your script sending any output before you are setting cookie?

Comment: @user3475797 You should enable error handling and error display to see if you get any messages.

Comment: No, the cookie is set then I do some echo's. Error handling is also turned on in the config file and also checked the settings of the session/cookies

Comment: Even if I try to create completely new cookie, still "cookie not set":
'setcookie("winkelwagen11", "some_value",time() + (86400 * 30), '/');

        if(!isset($_COOKIE["winkelwagen11"])) {
            echo "<br>Cookie is not set!";
        } else {
            echo "<br>Cookie '" . $_COOKIE["winkelwagen11"] . "' is set!";
            echo "<br>Value is: " . $_COOKIE["winkelwagen11"];
            
        }'

Comment: @user3475797 Like I said in my answer, you code is supposed to fail / do that on a clean page load.

Comment: When i relead page it still says cookie not set

Comment: My chrome browser show that there are cookies from localhost though

Answer (score 1):

You've made a mistake, you didn't set`life time` (it is `third` parameter), but you set there `path '/'`, which must be the `fourth` parameter. Also cookie doesn't set with empty value.

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php):

> If the value argument is an empty string, or FALSE, and all other
>   arguments match a previous call to setcookie, then the cookie with the
>   specified name will be deleted from the remote client.

Use this:

```
 setcookie("winkelwagen", "some_value",time() + (86400 * 30), '/') //for eaxmle 86400 = 1 day
```

Comment: When i do: setcookie("winkelwagen", ""); it also does not work. So just name and value

Comment: try as in my example, it will set after reload the page.

Comment: Still no change. Cookie is not set

Comment: Do you  reload the page? this works setcookie("winkelwagen11", "some_value",time() + (86400 * 30), '/'); As in my example. I checked.

Comment: Yes i reloaded the page